# Graviton propagator action

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, fourier-transform, quantum-gravity, propagator

I have a quadratic action for graviton (indicated $\gamma$ with spatial indices only, we assume that $\gamma_{ii} = \partial_i \gamma_{ij} = 0$):

\begin{equation}
S_{\gamma \gamma} = \int d^4 x \frac{1}{2}\gamma_{ij}\partial^\mu \partial_\mu \gamma_{kl} \delta^{ik}\delta^{jl}.
\end{equation}

I am trying to find the corresponding propagator in momentum space. My attempt:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{\gamma \gamma} = \frac{1}{2} \gamma_{ij} \partial^2 \gamma_{kl} (\frac{1}{2}(\delta^{ik}\delta^{jl} + \delta^{il}\delta^{jk}) - \delta^{ij}\delta^{kl}).
\end{equation}

Such that in Fourier space one has the expression:

\begin{equation}
(-k^2)\Big(\frac{1}{2}(\delta^{ik}\delta^{jl} + \delta^{il}\delta^{jk}) - \delta^{ij}\delta^{kl}\Big)D_{klpq}(k) = \frac{i}{2}(\delta^i_p \delta^j_q + \delta^i_q \delta^j_p),
\end{equation}

and therefore

\begin{equation}
D_{klpq}(k) = -\frac{i}{2k^2}(\delta_{kp}\delta_{lq} + \delta_{kq}\delta_{lp} - \delta_{kl}\delta_{pq}).
\end{equation}

Does this seem right or am I missing something?